# How to change access token with refresh token when it expires?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, refresh-token

I am doing an Alamofire request, and during login, it gives me access token and refresh token. After getting access token, I save it in keychain. Every 20 minutes the access token expires and I need to convert it to refresh token.
Below is the code of saving in keychain.

```
final class KeychainManager {
        let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.app")
        
        func saveToken(token: String) {
            do {
                try keychain.set(token, key: "accessToken")
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        func getAccessToken() -> String? {
            let token = try? keychain.getString(accessTokenKey)
            return token
        }
    }
```

And here is my Alamofire request

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiFormData in
            for form in bodyKeyValue {
                multiFormData.append(Data(form.sValue.utf8), withName: form.sKey)
            }
        }, to: url).responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponseBody.self, from: response.data!)
                    self.keychain.saveToken(token: decodedData.data.accessToken)
                    completion(.success(decodedData))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.serverError))
                }
            case .failure(_):
                print("fail")
            }
        }
```

Now I don't know how to use , refresh token here, so when access token expires, it will be converted to refresh token. Does Alamofire have a function for that?

Comment: There is no universal approach, it depends on the API you are using. Read the documentation or provide more details, so we can help

Comment: You can use the RequestInterceptor, detect a token expired (401 ? Message in body ?) and ask for a new token?

Answer (score 0):

Generally as a good rule of thumb.
When your access token expires and you need to use the refresh token.
What you should do is:

When the app makes the API call and the token is no longer valid (IE: time to use refresh) , when the call fails here in the do block.

```
do {

            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponseBody.self, from: response.data!)
            self.keychain.saveToken(token: decodedData.data.accessToken)
            completion(.success(decodedData))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(.serverError))
        }
```

When the  `completionHandler(.failure(.serverError))` is triggered
You can make another call here to retrieve the refresh token/generate a new one. Either inside this function or in the viewController.

so in your app, when your function call returns `completionHandler(.failure(.serverError))` , add the function call into the app(either in the failure block or inside the viewController, depending on your app and dev preference) on failure retrieve new access token/refresh token then make the same API called that failed.